# Why am i receiving an error after a successful async call in react native Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, promise

I'm still learning about react-native.

After I make a successful call to delete a file from my record, I then try to attempt to print out a success message to the console but instead I'm receiving an error stated below. Any pointers to where I'm going wrong?

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 
'server.deleteLocation(userUID, {
    streetName: streetName,
    long: long,
    lat: lat
  }).then')
```

Here is my firebase call (in a seperate file. Ive checked this code and it 100% works!):

```
const deleteLocation = (uid, locationObject) => {
 console.log('firebase deleteLocation............ START');

 firestore()
 .collection('Users')
 .doc(uid)
 .update({
  locations: firestore.FieldValue.arrayRemove({
     streetName: locationObject.streetName,
     longitude: locationObject.long,
     latitude: locationObject.lat,
   }),
 })
 .then(() => {
   console.log('firebase deleteLocation............ SUCCESS');
 })
 .catch((errorsss) => {
   console.log('firebase deleteLocation............ FAILED');
   throw errorsss;
  });
 };
```

Here is my calling code (here is where the problem occurs)

```
             ........imports
 import * as server from '../api/firebase';


deleteLocation = (streetName, long, lat) => {
server
  .deleteLocation(userUID, { streetName, long, lat })
  .then(() => {
    console.log('DELETE WAS SUCESSSS');
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log('ERROR CAUGHT IN DELETING PROGRAM');
    console.log(error);
  });
 };
```

Comment: What is the exact value of `server`?  Is it undefined?  Where do you assign it?

Comment: @DougStevenson    import * as server from '../api/firebase';

Comment: @DougStevenson is just an import to a file called firebase where I make firebase API calls. The method works I've checked it on my console

Comment: If you're not showing all the relevant code here, you should edit the question to show the [complete, minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that doesn't work the way you expect.  Be sure to explain what you've done to debug the code.

Comment: @DougStevenson this is the minimal example

Comment: If we can't see exactly where all the variables come from, or at least their specific values, it's neither minimal nor complete.  There should be enough information in the question that anyone can use to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Your method `deleteLocation` that you have written on separate file is not `async` method, and you are trying to access `.then` on that method so that's why this error is coming. Here is the solution.

Make your `deleteLocation` async :

```js
const deleteLocation = async (uid, locationObject) => {
  console.log('firebase deleteLocation............ START');

  await firestore()
  .collection('Users')
  .doc(uid)
  .update({
    locations: firestore.FieldValue.arrayRemove({
      streetName: locationObject.streetName,
      longitude: locationObject.long,
      latitude: locationObject.lat,
    }),
  })
  .catch((errorsss) => {
    console.log('firebase deleteLocation............ FAILED');
    throw errorsss;
  });
};
```

Now, you can access `.then` and error will gone.

Comment: Alternatively, you can just return the existing promise rather than use async/await. `firestore().collection(...)...` to `return firestore().collection(...)...`